# Can I apply a certain style for results from validation to only one button?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, idataerrorinfo

I'm working on a WPF-application in which I make validation with a mix of IDataErrorInfo and validation rules.
For displaying the results of the validation at runtime I have made some styles in the XAML of the window.
One of these styles should disable the save-button as long as there is an input error:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--Disabling the Save-button by style not viewmodel-property-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbx_firstname, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbx_lastname, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbx_age, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have two problems:

1. The style disables all buttons on the window. What can I do to only disable the save-button?
   I tried the following, but there seems to be a syntax-error (VS doesn't accept it):

   ```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Name btn_save}">
   ```
2. In the style for the save-button I have to check each control that is validated.
   Is there another possibility to make that part shorter and less error-prone (because it has to combined with the viewmodel)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your style to be applied to a single button instead of all of them, you need to assign a key to the style, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="SaveButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

That way it will not be applied implicitly to all buttons. To apply it to your save button, explicitly specify the style on the button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SaveButtonStyle}">
```

Comment: Thank You very much Manfred! I have found out the same at one minute ago. Just a little key makes such a difference.